# How $.contains() jquery function Works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and don't know how $.contains() works in jQuery..
I tried this code and I know it gives boolean value but don't know how it works exactly..

html:

```
<div>
<span>MM</span>
</div>
```

jquery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 if($.contains( $('div'), $('span') ) ==  true){
     alert('yup');
     };
});
```

Can anyone  explain...

Comment: jQuery *does* provide documentation for these things: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Comment: @David I already read that but couldn't understand can you please explain in simple engish with a simple example

Comment: Well, *"Check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element"* -> `jQuery.contains( container, contained )`, I'm not sure it can be explained any simpler ?

Comment: @adeneo thanks for reply I tried that but it alwasy provide ture (boolean )...can you please see the code above I tried  am i doing something wrong here

Comment: It doesn't really work on jQuery collections, it's supposed to be used with two specific native DOM elements, like `$.contains( $('div').get(0), $('span').get(0) )` etc.

Comment: Otherwise you'd just do `$('div:has(span)').length`

Comment: @Lucky: Well, maybe it returns true because the `div` in your HTML contains a `span`.  What else would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` jQuery method looks for the second argument to be a child or descendant of the first argument. While the first arguments NEEDS to be a DOM object such as an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) or [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) type, I have also noticed unexpected behavior if the second argument is not a DOM object as well (like passing in jQuery collection).

You should always stick with using individual nodes (like Element or Document) with this method. If you need to check multiple items, use a loop or iterator method (see my JSFiddle example below).

Think of the DOM (document object model) as a tree. The tree has a stem and branches. The root is the `html` element. From there you have branches `head` and `body`. Each of those branch further into other elements. Each branch may or may not contain other elements. If a particular branch (known individually as a node) contains other nodes, those immediately contained nodes are known as children or child nodes of the current node you are looking at. Those child nodes any any children of them (as well the children of them, the children of them, and so on) are known as descendants of the current node. For instance, if you were currently looking at the `body` node, here are some identifications for containing, sibling, and parent/ancestor nodes:

```
html (parent of body and also an ancestor of body)
  --> head (previous and prior sibling of body)
    --> title
  --> body (assume you are currently looking at this node)
    --> header (this is a child and descendant of body)
      --> div (this is a descendant of body)
    --> section (this is a child and descendant of body)
      --> div (this is a descendant of body)
        --> p (this is a descendant of body)
    --> p (this is a child and descendant of body)
    --> span (this is a child and descendant of body)
    --> footer (this is a child and descendant of body)
      --> div (this is a descendant of body)
```

Here is an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ab3whke/) I created to show you a working example.

In case the fiddle disappears, here is the HTML and JavaScript:

```
<div id="first">
   <span id="first-inner"></span>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <span id="second-inner"></span>
</div>

<div id="loop">
  <span id="loop-inner" class="check-loop"></span>
</div>

<span id="loop-outer" class="check-loop"></span>

<div id="extra-messages">
</div>
```

```
// Is #first-inner a descendant of #first?
if( jQuery.contains(jQuery("#first").get(0), jQuery("#first-inner").get(0)) ) {
    jQuery("#first-inner").text("Span with id 'first-inner' is a descendant of the div with id 'first'");
} else {
    jQuery("#first-inner").text("Span with id 'first-inner' is NOT a descendant of the div with id 'first'");
}

// Is #second-inner a descendant of #first?
if( jQuery.contains( jQuery("#first").get(0), jQuery("#second-inner").get(0) ) ) {
    jQuery("#second-inner").text("Span with id 'second-inner' is a descendant of the div with id 'first'");
} else {
    jQuery("#second-inner").text("Span with id 'second-inner' is NOT a descendant of the div with id 'first'");
}

// Loop it!
jQuery(".check-loop").each(function(idx, item){
    if( jQuery.contains( jQuery("#loop").get(0), item) ) {
    jQuery("#extra-messages").append( jQuery("<div>div</div>").text("Span with id '" + jQuery(item).attr("id") + "' is a descendant of the div with id 'loop'"));
  } else {
    jQuery("#extra-messages").append( jQuery("<div></div>").text("Span with id '" + jQuery(item).attr("id") + "' is NOT a descendant of the div with id 'loop'") );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Native nodes have an inclusive [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method:

> The `Node.contains()` method returns a Boolean value indicating
>   whether a node is a descendant of a given node or not.

Ignoring little details, jQuery's exclusive `$.contains(a,b)` is just

```
a.contains(b.parentNode);
```

More specifically, it's defined as

```js
// Element contains another
// Purposefully self-exclusive
// As in, an element does not contain itself
contains = hasCompare || rnative.test( docElem.contains ) ?
  function( a, b ) {
    var adown = a.nodeType === 9 ? a.documentElement : a,
        bup = b && b.parentNode;
    return a === bup || !!( bup && bup.nodeType === 1 && (
      adown.contains ?
        adown.contains( bup ) :
        a.compareDocumentPosition && a.compareDocumentPosition( bup ) & 16
    ));
  } :
  function( a, b ) {
    if ( b ) {
      while ( (b = b.parentNode) ) {
        if ( b === a ) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
```